How to vertically autoscroll text, if the text overflows the div area
I've created a rail app that pulls in rail data. Sometimes the via departure information overflows the allowed div area.
How can I automatically scroll that text vertically IF the text overflows the designated div?
I'm using a combination CSS and JavaScript but I haven't added in any animation to this as not sure of the beat way to approach this. EDIT I'm now using jquery scroller, works great horizontally but im having trouble`


        function setupScrollers() {
            var scrollSpace = $('.horizontal_scroll_space');
            var scrollText = $('.scrollingtext');

            var numberOfScrollers = scrollSpace.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < numberOfScrollers; i++) {
                if (scrollSpace[i].clientWidth < scrollText[i].clientWidth) {
                    scrollSpace[i].setAttribute("class", "active_scroller");
                }
            }

            //create scroller for each element with "horizontal_scroller" class...
            $('.active_scroller').SetScroller({
                velocity: 70,
                direction: 'vertical',
                startfrom: 'top',
                loop: 'infinite',
                movetype: 'linear',
                onstartup: 'play'
            });
        }
body {
        background: #000;
        color: #fff;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        font-size: 5vh;    
    }
    div.horizontal_scroll_space, div.active_scroller {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    left: 5%;
    width: 70%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.scrollingtext {
    position: absolute;
    white-space: normal;
    font-size: 80%;
    color: #ECD2E1;
}
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://publicnottsderby.rslepi.co.uk/departureboards/js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://publicnottsderby.rslepi.co.uk/departureboards/js/jquery-scroller.js"></script> 
<body onload="setupScrollers()">

    <div class="horizontal_scroll_space" id="no_mouse_events">
        <div class="scrollingtext">
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
            </div>
      </div>

</body>



` identifying the height instead of width for the vertical scroll**


 body {
        background: #000;
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
        color: #fff;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0;
        width: 500px;
        height: 5000px;
        font-size: 6vh;
    }



    .depContainer {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        top: 7%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 93%;
        display: grid;
        grid-gap: 0;
        grid-template-rows: 20;
    }

    .depContainer>div {

        padding: 20px 0;
        font-size: 2vh;
        font-weight: 700;
        border-bottom: #ddd 2px solid;
    }

    .deps {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .rdue {
        left: 1%;
        width: 12%;
    }

    .rdest {
        left: 13%;
        width: 51%;
    }

    .rplatform {
        left: 63%;
        width: 11%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .rstatus {
        left: 73.5%;
        width: 26%;
        text-align: right;
    }

    .rvias {
        position: absolute;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-align: left;
        left: 1%;
        width: 98%;
        font-size: 1.6vh;
        margin-top: 6%;
        max-height: 5%;
    }
<div class="depContainer">

        <!-- Row 2 -->
        <div>
            <div id="RTime0" class="deps rdue">Due</div>
            <div id="RDest0" class="deps rdest">Destination</div>
            <div id="REstimatedTimeOfDepartureComment0" class="deps rstatus">Status</div>
            <div id="RStand0" class="deps rplatform">Platform</div>
            <div id="RVias0" class="deps rvias">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque mi
                erat, finibus id purus non, lobortis imperdiet elit. Praesent et felis rhoncus, maximus lectus eu,
                volutpat ante. Fusce consequat ultricies nunc. In non eros tortor. Integer ultrices eu metus vitae
                lobortis. Praesent pretium, tortor vitae efficitur pharetra, orci urna porta nibh, vel egestas neque
                quam in erat. Aliquam lorem mauris, semper a sollicitudin at, consectetur quis ligula. Sed quis tortor
                nec nisl pretium vehicula. Curabitur sed dui a erat malesuada efficitur.</div>
        </div>

        <!-- Row 2 -->
        <div>
            <div id="RTime1" class="deps rdue">Due</div>
            <div id="RDest1" class="deps rdest">Destination</div>
            <div id="REstimatedTimeOfDepartureComment1" class="deps rstatus">Status</div>
            <div id="RStand1" class="deps rplatform">Platform</div>
            <div id="RVias1" class="deps rvias">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque mi
                erat, finibus id purus non, lobortis imperdiet elit. Praesent et felis rhoncus, maximus lectus eu,
                volutpat ante. Fusce consequat ultricies nunc. In non eros tortor. Integer ultrices eu metus vitae
                lobortis. Praesent pretium, tortor vitae efficitur pharetra, orci urna porta nibh, vel egestas neque
                quam in erat. Aliquam lorem mauris, semper a sollicitudin at, consectetur quis ligula. Sed quis tortor
                nec nisl pretium vehicula. Curabitur sed dui a erat malesuada efficitur.</div>
        </div>


    </div>




Here is a codepen i found that should suit you needs: https://codepen.io/pprakash/pen/oNxNeQE


function Marquee(selector, speed) {
  const parentSelector = document.querySelector(selector);
  const clone = parentSelector.innerHTML;
  const firstElement = parentSelector.children[0];
  let i = 0;
  console.log(firstElement);
  parentSelector.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', clone);
  parentSelector.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', clone);

  setInterval(function () {
    firstElement.style.marginLeft = `-${i}px`;
    if (i > firstElement.clientWidth) {
      i = 0;
    }
    i = i + speed;
  }, 0);
}

//after window is completed load
//1 class selector for marquee
//2 marquee speed 0.2
window.addEventListener('load', Marquee('.marquee', 0.2))
.marquee {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
}

.marquee h1{
  font-size: 5em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-transform: uppercase
}
<div class="marquee">
  <h1>Nepal * Himalayas * Mountains * Everest</h1>
</div>



Edit: This isn't my code, full credit to the guy that wrote that codepen

Thank you @Symtox however that isn't what i'm trying to achieve. I need the text to automatically scroll if the text overflows, some kind of animation whether it be js or css. This information will be placed on a non interactive display.

Oh mb i didn't notice about the "automatically", i'll check this one out. So you are looking for some kind of marquee thing ?

I have fixed this. I used jQuery scroller and added the below script to allow vertical scrolling


function setupScrollers() {
    var scrollSpace = $('.horizontal_scroll_space');
    var scrollText = $('.scrollingtext');

    var numberOfScrollers = scrollSpace.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfScrollers; i++) {
         if (scrollSpace[i].clientHeight < scrollText[i].clientHeight) {
              scrollSpace[i].setAttribute("class", "active_scroller");
         }
    }

    //create scroller for each element with "horizontal_scroller" class...
    $('.active_scroller').SetScroller({
         velocity: 70,
         direction: 'vertical',
         startfrom: 'bottom',
         loop: 'infinite',
         movetype: 'linear',
         onstartup: 'play'
    });
}
body {
  background: #000;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  width: 1080px;
  height: 1920px;
}
div.horizontal_scroll_space, div.active_scroller {
    height: 200px;
    left: 1%;
    width: 98%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 2vh;
  margin-top: 6%;
  max-height: 4.5%;
}
div.scrollingtext {
    position: absolute;
    white-space: normal;
}
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-scroller.js"></script>
<div class="horizontal_scroll_space" id="no_mouse_events">
                    <div class="scrollingtext deps">
                         <div >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus. Volutpat consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris. Cursus risus at ultrices mi tempus. Auctor neque vitae tempus quam pellentesque nec nam. Facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a. Nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan. A lacus vestibulum sed arcu non odio. Semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet sit amet cursus sit. Enim blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam. Amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante in nibh.
                         </div>
                    </div>
               </div>



